# Google Map Zoom To Fit

Tags: google-maps, zooming

I have developed a map that uses a geo-coordinate from a database using a cluster marker example. I have tried to make it zoom automaticly by using `LatLngBounds();`

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function initialize() {
            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(9.4419, 9.1419);

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 2,
              center: center,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var markers = [];
            // create the infowindow out of the for boucle
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for ( var i = 0; i < latlng.length; i++ ) {

      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlng.lat,latlng.lng);   

     var html = 'test show in infowondow';

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            icon:"/img/icon1.jpg",
            title:"test title",
        });
    // call to the function....
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    markers.push(marker);

  }     

            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
          }

    // create a function bindInfoWindow

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
    }

            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
          }
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
```

Comment: If you separate your Javascript from the PHP(?), or whatever language it is, you might notice that you're creating a LatLngBounds object, but then you never use it. Try to see the same as the browser sees. :-)

Comment: i have remove the php code here do you a suggestion? please

Comment: Have you tested the Javascript you posted? It cannot possibly run without crashing. Where is latlng defined? Is it an array? If yes then it doesn't have properties called latlng.lat and latlng.lng. Is the browser not giving you some useful error messages? (Use a proper browser, not IE) :-)

Answer (score 1):

- make bounds global.
- then after

`var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlng.lat,latlng.lng);`

EDIT: and as Marcelo pointed out change this to:

`var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlng[i].lat,latlng[i].lng);`

add:

`bounds.extend(latLng)`

- after

`var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);`

add:

`map.fitBounds(bounds);`